# How to make array compact after unsetting an index of it?

Tags: php

There is an array :

```
$ret = array();
... query execution
$ret['cnt'] = $this->db->num_rows(); // total number of database records
$i = 0;
while ( $this->db->next_record() ) { // fetching database records
    $ret[$i]["user_id"] = $this->db->f('user_id') ;
    $ret[$i]["user_login"] = stripslashes($this->db->f('user_login'));
    $i++;
}
```

Now I want to remove from this array the element whose "user_id" is equal to a particular value :

```
if ($ret['cnt'] > 0) {
                for ($i=0; $i<$ret['cnt']; $i++) {
                    if ($ret[$i]['user_id'] == $_SESSION[CODE_USER]) {
                        unset($ret[$i]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

After printing the array I noticed that the element 0 is not in the array , this is what I am expecting. The only problem is now how to rearrange the array elements so that it will be compact again without any hole in its elements because the element 0 is not present ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use array_values:

```
$ret = array_values($ret);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Or instead of using the 0th index. You could just grab the first element with reset.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php

Answer (score 1):

[`array_values`](http://php.net/array-values) is probably the simplest way to reset keys.

Comment: or `sort`, if the order is irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($ret['cnt'] > 0) {
                for ($i=0; $i<$ret['cnt']; $i++) {
                    if ($ret[$i]['user_id'] == $_SESSION[CODE_USER]) {
                        $ret = array_slice($ret,$i,1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

[`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) will also strip away a section of the array and re-index as necessary.